# Trace ActivityId getting reset in WCF error handler

Tags: c#, wcf, trace, ierrorhandler

I have a WCF service with an implementation of IErrorHandler. In its HandleError method I am logging the exception using a TraceSource:

```
public bool HandleError(Exception error)
{
    tracer.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Error, 0, error.ToString());
    return true;
}
```

However, when this method is entered the Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId has changed from what I set it to at the start of the service method. So I get a log entry with some random activity ID, which kind of ruins the activity trace.

Is WCF doing this? and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do some extra work due to WCF.

See if this link helps:

[Extending / Custom FaultContractExceptionHandler for Exception Handling in WCF](http://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/400959)